# Unable to navigate a symbolic link

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a link by searching a folder but it not working

Let say i am running this command in target directory where glassfish is a folder and it contains a folder with name like gfembed2955792773745257233tmp. This gfembed2955792773745257233tmp is dynamically creating by the server so everytime it change the name so that i am searching with wildcard gfembed*  and then creating a link. Here is my command:

```
   ln -s 'find . -name gfembed*' gfembededlink
```

after when link is created and if i want to navigate like:

```
cd gfembededlink
```

it give error `-bash: cd: gfembededlink: No such file or directory` Can someone tell me why i cant navigate to this link throug cd command or i making link in a wring way?

Comment: you might have better luck on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

Comment: You think you have called `find`? Try `ls -l gfembededlink`.